# How to enable setup python app on cpanel?

Tags: python, django, cpanel, whm

I want to start my new Django project on my server. so i install cpanel. but in software part, there is nothing related to python.

Should i Do something in WHM? or install something in my server?

thanks for helping me.

Comment: This will help you: https://libyanspider.com/knowledge/install-run-python-django-using-cpanel/

Comment: It’s ok when i do in my localhost but in my server and with cpanel it dosnt work

Comment: see the updated link.

Comment: CPanel is a server management tool and therefore off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1):

python app (django & flask) are available on cpanel only if CloudLinux is installed , so you have to install a CloudLinux on your server and then try to setup a python app using cpanel interface .

Comment: What about the "Application Manager"? Can I use that for my Django API Project?

Answer (score 1):

You must upgrade your OS to Cloudlinux then you will have that feature.

When you have Cloudlinux installed, you will have an option in WHM called "Live Manager" where you can activate Python.